# Cookie Data only stores one variable after leaving home page

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, variables, cookies

I'm having a problem here. I'm converting a cookie string creating variables. Home page it shows both variables in console. Things are looking good. Have an If statement which I figure is where my problem is. After I leave the home page only the mc_eid is being stored. i need to see both the mc_eid and the mc_cid. They both show up on home page but as soon as we change the link it looks like only the mc_eid is being stored. I'm having a hard time figuring this out. at checkout I need both variable ids. How come once the url changes it only stores one of them?

```
  // getParameterByName  
  function getParameterByName( name ){ 
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)", 
  regex = new RegExp( regexS ), 
  results = regex.exec( window.location.search ); 
  if( results === null ){ 
  return null; 
  } else{ 
  return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " ")); 
  } 
  } 

  // call Parameter values we are looking for
  var mc_emailId = getParameterByName('mc_eid'); 
  var mc_campaignId = getParameterByName('mc_cid'); 

  //if id's are present store in cookie
  if (mc_campaignId && mc_emailId) { 
  mccookie = "mc_eid=" + mc_emailId + "; mc_cid=" + mc_campaignId; 
  }else if (mc_campaignId) { 
  mccookie = "mc_cid=" + mc_campaignId; 
  }else if (mc_emailId) { 
  mccookie = "mc_eid=" + mc_emailId; 
  } 

  // add experation date set cookie
  if (typeof mccookie !== "undefined"){
    var days = 30; 
    var d = new Date(); 
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000)); 
    var expires =";expires="+d.toUTCString(); 
    document.cookie = mccookie + expires + "; domain=.mydomainname.com; path=/";
  }
```

i just don't understand why the mc_cid isn't being stored.

Comment: not sure if I'm writing this correctly,  mccookie = "mc_eid=" + mc_emailId + "; mc_cid=" + mc_campaignId;

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the error is related to:

```
mccookie = "mc_eid=" + mc_emailId + "; mc_cid=" + mc_campaignId;
```

You need to set the cookies separately. Something like:

```
if (mc_campaignId) { 
  var mccookieCID = "mc_cid=" + mc_campaignId; 
}
if (mc_emailId) { 
  var mccookieEID = "mc_eid=" + mc_emailId; 
} 

// add experation date set cookies
if (typeof mccookieCID !== "undefined"){
    var days = 30; 
    var d = new Date(); 
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000)); 
    var expires =";expires="+d.toUTCString(); 
    document.cookie = mccookieCID + expires + "; domain=.mydomainname.com; path=/";
}

if (typeof mccookieEID !== "undefined"){
    var days = 30; 
    var d = new Date(); 
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000)); 
    var expires =";expires="+d.toUTCString(); 
    document.cookie = mccookieEID + expires + "; domain=.mydomainname.com; path=/";
}
```

It might be more efficient to just push any cookie values into an array and then loop through it to set them. You could also consider using a JavaScript Cookie API (like [JS Cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)). But to fix your code you just need to set the cookies separately.

Comment: Joe thank you, I'm still learning how to loop down i see what you mean though. very helpful

Comment: looks like if (typeof mccookieEID !== "undefined") is being used out of scope I'm getting an error